# How to sort posts with next-mdx-remote?

Tags: next.js, mdxjs

I'm working on a blog in Next.js and MDX. For this, I downloaded [this repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mdx-remote) which I'm trying to adapt. But I can't find how I can sort the posts. For now they are with alphabetical order, but I would like to sort them by date (or a custom sort). How can I do this?

This is the code:

```
{posts.map((post) => (
    <section key={post.filePath}>
        <Link
            as={`/posts/${post.filePath.replace(/\.mdx?$/, "")}`}
            href={`/posts/[slug]`}
        >
            <a>{post.data.title}</a>
        </Link>
    </section>
))}
```

```
export function getStaticProps() {
    const posts = postFilePaths.map((filePath) => {
        const source = fs.readFileSync(path.join(POSTS_PATH, filePath));
        const { content, data } = matter(source);

        return {
            content,
            data,
            filePath,
        };
    });

    return { props: { posts } };
}
```

EDIT:

I tried to sort the map of elements. It worked, but every time I do a reload of the page it goes back to alphabetical order. From where this can come from?

This is my new code:

```
const SortedPosts = posts.sort((a, b) =>
    a.position > b.position ? 1 : -1
);
```

```
{SortedPosts.map((post) => (
    <section key={post.filePath} position={post.data.position}>
        <Link
            as={`/posts/${post.filePath.replace(/\.mdx?$/, "")}`}
            href={`/posts/[slug]`}
        >
            <a>{post.data.title}</a>
        </Link>
    </section>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a separate variable for SortedPosts, you can simply sort the existing array of posts in-place using the sort function before returning it in `getStaticProps()`

```js
export function getStaticProps() {
    const posts = postFilePaths.map((filePath) => {
    // existing code
    });

    posts.sort((a, b) => a.position > b.position ? 1 : -1 );
    return { props: { posts } };
}
```

TIP: if you'd like to reverse the order, you can simply swap `-1` and `1` for eg: from `1 : -1` to  `-1 : 1`

---

**Reference**: Check out this question which has more alternatives and details on sorting - [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67992215/6908282)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to write the logic yourself, import a library such as `lodash`. After that, inside your getStaticProps function, before returning the posts do the following:

```
const sortedPosts = _.reverse(_.sortBy(posts, (post) => post.data.publishedOn))

return { props: { posts: sortedPosts } }
```